# php - html form $_POST undefined index on only one element of the form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I encountered a bug today : I have an html form with several input elements which posts them to a php file. I keep on getting the undefined index error because one of the form element doesn't get posted. Here's my html code (simplified) (/forms/form.php) :

```
<form action="/php/save.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="SpeakerWeek1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="SpeakerWeek2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="SpeakerWeek3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="SpeakerWeek4"/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="ReaderWeek1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="ReaderWeek2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="ReaderWeek3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="ReaderWeek4"/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</form>
```

Now, here's my php code (simplified too) (/php/save.php) :

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $SpeakerWeek1 = $_POST['SpeakerWeek1'];
        $SpeakerWeek2 = $_POST['SpeakerWeek2'];
        $SpeakerWeek3 = $_POST['SpeakerWeek3'];
        $SpeakerWeek4 = $_POST['SpeakerWeek4'];
        // the above code works fine (I get no undefined index error for it)
        // but the following code keeps on causing an undefined index notice and I don't get why 
        $ReaderWeek1 = $_POST['ReaderWeek1'];
        $ReaderWeek2 = $_POST['ReaderWeek2'];
        $ReaderWeek3 = $_POST['ReaderWeek3'];
        $ReaderWeek4 = $_POST['ReaderWeek4'];
    }
?>
```

I keep on getting this error :

```
Notice: Undefined Index: ReaderWeek1 in /var/www/html/php/save.php
Notice: Undefined Index: ReaderWeek2 in /var/www/html/php/save.php
Notice: Undefined Index: ReaderWeek3 in /var/www/html/php/save.php
Notice: Undefined Index: ReaderWeek4 in /var/www/html/php/save.php
```

I already had a look at other threads but none actually matched my situation.
Do you have any idea why I get this error and why specific form elements don't get posted while all the others do ? 
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: are you passing these fields through form submit?

Comment: Try to do `print_r($_POST);` and see what it displays

Comment: typo missing close parenthesis in this line  if(isset($_POST['submit']) {

Comment: You didn't close the if statement if(isset($_POST['submit']). Either you posted a wrong code or by mistake you missed it.

Comment: Check your $_POST-Variables before you use them!

Comment: There is nothing wrong , i have tested locally.

Comment: I mistyped, But this doesn't change the error I get

Comment: If that is what `print_r` displays then you don't have to worry about those notices.

Comment: The thing is that I can't access the data the user entered in those input fields while I can access the data the user entered in the other input fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check your $_POST-Variables before using them.

```
if($_POST['SpeechmanWeek1']){
 $SpeechmanWeek1 = $_POST['SpeechmanWeek1'];
}else{
 $SpeechmanWeek1 = 'whateveryouwant';
}
```